# Display Lookup ID into list view

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, lookup-column, column

How can I display the **lookup Id** (of a lookup field) instead of title into a **list view**? 
I am using SharePoint 2013 on-premise.

Comment: Which is your SharePoint version?

Comment: Updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional lookup field or select lookup field as ID in field settings:

- To Select Lookup Field as ID instead of Title:
  [image]
- To Select ID as well as Title
  [image]

[image]